# How do I concatenate columns in two pandas dataframes with different indexes and non-unique keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have one dataframe called `products` that looks like this:

```
   order_number  sku  units revenue
1  5000          754  1     20.0
2  5000          900  4     30.0
3  5001          754  2     40.0
4  5002          754  10    200.0
.  ...           ...  ..    ...
```

and another called `orders` that looks like this

```
   date    order_number  units revenue  country new_customer ...
1  1-jan   5000          5     50.0     russia  yes          
2  1-jan   5001          2     40.0     china   yes          
3  2-jan   5002          10    200.0    france  no
4  2-jan   5003          1     70.0     brazil  yes
.  ....    ...           ..    ...      ...
```

I would like to create a single dataframe, which has the rows from the `products` dataframe but additionally has the columns from the `orders` dataframe, where the order number in `orders` matches the order number in `products`.

I've tried to find a way to express this via both `pandas.concat` and `pandas.merge`, but I can't get around the problem that the key I'm joining on (order_number) is unique in the `orders` dataframe but not in the `products` dataframe.

How do I do a many-to-one join like this in pandas?

Comment: This does not work? `products.merge(orders, on='order_number')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (you have to provide a suffix since you have a duplicate column `revenue`):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> products = pd.DataFrame({'order_number': [5000, 5000, 5001, 5002, 5004],
...                          'sku':          [ 754,  900,  754,  754,  900],
...                          'revenue':      [20.0, 30.0, 40.0,200.0, 90.0]})
>>> orders   = pd.DataFrame({'order_number': [5000, 5001, 5002, 5003],
...                          'units':        [   5,    2,   10,    1],
...                          'revenue':      [50.0, 40.0,200.0, 70.0]})
>>> products.join(orders.set_index('order_number'), 'order_number', rsuffix='_o')
   order_number  revenue  sku  revenue_o  units
0          5000       20  754         50      5
1          5000       30  900         50      5
2          5001       40  754         40      2
3          5002      200  754        200     10
4          5004       90  900        NaN    NaN
```

*Edit*: the same result can be achieved with `products.merge(orders, 'left', 'order_number', suffixes=('', '_o'))`